# Are typedef's handled by the preprocessor?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, typedef

Are `typedef`'s handled by C's preprocessor?

That is, is `typedef int foo_t;` the same as `#define foo_t int`?

Comment: In a word: no. (oops, that's too short for SO comments)

Comment: `typedef` is treated as a storage-class specifier (along with `extern`, `static`, `auto`, `register`) for syntax purposes, although it isn't really a *storage class*.  It just indicates that instead of declaring an *object* of type `T`, it declares a *synonym* for type `T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because that type of replacement won't work with more complex types. For instance:

```
typedef int tenInts[10];
tenInts myIntArray;
```

The declaration of `myIntArray` is equivalent to:

```
int myIntArray[10];
```

To do this as a macro you'd have to make it a function-style, so it can insert the variable name in the middle of the expansion.

```
#define tenInts(var) int var[10]
```

and use it like:

```
tenInts(myIntArray);
```

This also wouldn't work for declaring multiple variables. You'd have to write

```
tenInts(myArray1);
tenints(myArray2);
```

You can't write

```
tenInts myArray1, myArray2;
```

like you can with a `typedef`.

Comment: note that `typedef int[10] tenInts;` does not compile

Comment: @ian5v Good catch. It can actually be done using a function-style macro. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**No**.

---

As an example,

```
typedef int *int_ptr1;
#define int_ptr2  int *
```

Then in:

```
int_ptr1 a, b;
int_ptr2 c, d;
```

`a` and `b` are both pointers to `int`. `c` is also a pointer to `int`, but `d` is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

No ,`typedef`( being a C **keyword**) is interpreted by compiler not by pre-processor whereas `#define` is processed by pre-processor.

Answer (score -1):

No - the C preprocessor doesn't handle typedefs.  The C preprocessor does not recognize the syntax of the C language; it will not know what is and is not a typedef.

The #define is strictly a text replacement of "int" for "foo_t"; the replacements done by the preprocessor occur prior to compilation.